# 400 bad request,Azure service management api config change

Tags: c#, azure, configuration-files, bad-request

my problem is that i am getting a 400 bad request when i try to get a responce to my HTTP request.
Can anyone tell me why this is happening and possibly how i can fix it?

The exact error is : 
          `BadRequest`No change in settings specified

I put in a breakpoint in my code before i pass in the configuration file, when i viewed it, it had changed what i wanted it to change and so the configuration file that already exists  is definetly diffirent to the one i am trying to change it with.

Here is the api info for the configuration change : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/ee460809.aspx

And Below is my code,Any help is greatly appreciated, thank you

```
public void changeConfiguration(string serviceName, string deploymentSlot, string  config, string deploymentName)
{
//encoding the config file
    byte[] encodedConfigbyte = new byte[config.Length];
     encodedConfigbyte = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(config);
    string temp = Convert.ToBase64String(encodedConfigbyte);

//creating the URI with the subscriptionID,serviceName and deploymentSlot
    Uri changeConfigRequestUri = new Uri("https://management.core.windows.net/" + subscriptionId +  "/services/hostedservices/" + serviceName + "/deploymentslots/" + deploymentSlot + "/?comp=config");

//creating a request using the URI
 HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(changeConfigRequestUri);

//Adding a header to the request
    request.Headers.Add("x-ms-version", "2010-10-28");
    request.Method = "POST";

//Create a string to hold the request body, temp being the config file
    string bodyText = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>" +
                      "<ChangeConfiguration xmlns=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/windowsazure\"" + ">"
                      + "<Configuration>" + temp + "</Configuration></ChangeConfiguration>";

//encoding the body
    byte[] buf = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(bodyText);
    request.ContentType = "application/xml";
    request.ContentLength = buf.Length;

//searches the cert store for a cert that has a matching thumbprint to the thumbprint supplied
    X509Store certStore = new X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.CurrentUser);
    try
    {
        certStore.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        if (e is CryptographicException)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Error: The store is unreadable.");
        }
        else if (e is SecurityException)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Error: You don't have the required permission.");
        }
        else if (e is ArgumentException)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Error: Invalid values in the store.");
        }
        else
        {
            throw;
        }
    }
    X509Certificate2Collection certCollection = certStore.Certificates.Find(X509FindType.FindByThumbprint, thumbprint, false);
    certStore.Close();
    if (certCollection.Count == 0)
    {
        throw new Exception("Error: No certificate found containing thumbprint ");
    }
    X509Certificate2 certificate = certCollection[0];

//cert is added to the request
request.ClientCertificates.Add(certificate);

//the requestBody is written to the request
    Stream dataStream = request.GetRequestStream();
    dataStream.Write(buf, 0, buf.Length);
    dataStream.Close();
    try
    {
    //retrieving responce
        WebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
    }
    catch (WebException e)
    {
         string test = new StreamReader(e.Response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: You might want to compare your solution with the [sample code on msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee460795.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

BadRequest means a parameter was incorrect.  My guess is that you are using a deploymentSlot of 0 instead of staging or production like it is mentioned here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee460786.aspx

Other then that, it would be great if you could show us the parameters you are passing in and we can maybe tell from that what is wrong.